# Spring jdbctemplate, datasource, transactionManager

Tags: java, spring

For a test, i have a abstract class.

```
public abstract class BaseTestClass

  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
  {
  this.setJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
  }
  ...
}


@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/spring/test/test-dao-context.xml"})
public class TestUser extends BaseTestClass{
...
}
```

In test-dao-context.xml file, i have my transaction manager  and datasource.

SetDataSource is never called, so i get a null pointerException when i try to do a test.

Comment: How have you configured the datasource, and also the component scanning? Can you show it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run you test with an appropriate runner which is `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` for Spring driven tests. Otherwise nothing will get injected anywhere as there is no Spring Container managing all the instances.

Check [Spring Unit Testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html) for details.